# PHP: Can you use an array as the arguments part of the sprintf function? if so - how?

Tags: php, arrays, printf

From the PHP API reference:

> string **sprintf**  ( string *$format*  [,
>   mixed *$args*  [, mixed $...  ]] )
>
> Returns a string produced according to
>   the formatting string format.

Can `$args` be an array - If so how would I use it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`vsprintf()` is your friend. You cannot use an array in `sprintf` in any meaningfull way, but you can call `vsprintf()` with an array of arguments (which replaces `sprintf` 's  seperate function arguments).